# Angular posted date string into Symfony2 Form DateTime field. Invalid value

Tags: php, angularjs, symfony, datetime, iso8601

I have a form built with Symfony2 FormBuilder.

Some of the fields are defined as:

```
$builder->add('dateField','datetime',array('widget'=>'singletext'))
```

When I use angular to $http.post back the content the value from the field comes back in the format:

```
"2015-07-31T23:00:00.000Z"
```

And the field gives me an invalid value err.

Can anyone advise how to make this work?

Comment: Try to set ISO8601 format manually: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html#reference-forms-type-date-format . And notice, that docs say it is 'single_text', not 'singletext'.

Answer (score 0):

I had almost the same issue except for that i used date field which comes with a widget of an option input seperatelly for day,month and year. 
I used bootstrapui for the fancy angular datepicker. 
Symfony's form post is a multi array, looks something similar to:
form_name[field_name][day], form_name[field_name][month] ,form_name[field_name][year] where the form name comes from the type's getName function. 
Basically you have to convert angular's date to this format:

```
//java script    
var expiration = $filter('date')($scope.datePicker, 'yyyy/M/d').split('/');       
        $scope.data['form_name[expiration][month]'] = expiration[1];
        $scope.data['form_name[expiration][day]'] = expiration[2];
        $scope.data['form_name[expiration][year]'] = expiration[0];


//form type
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
            parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
            $builder
                    ->add('expiration', 'date')                       
                    ->add('save','submit');

        }
    public function getName() {
    return 'form_name';
}
```

In the javascript $scope.datePicker is the ng-model binded to the picker (which stores the date object angular creates) and $filter is an angular service injected to the controller. Then you can post it:

```
$http.post($scope.formUrl, $.param($scope.data), {headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }})
                .then(function (response) {
                    //called async if form is valid
            }, function (response) {
                // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                // or server returns response with an error status.
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I get the same prob, i used datetimetype

`use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateTimeType;`

than in my postAction i added

`$date   = new \DateTime( $request->request->get("date") );
$entity->setDate($date)`

And finally, in my angular form a simple `input type="date"`

(Date is a DateTime btw)

`/**
* @var \DateTime
*
* @ORM\Column(name="date", type="datetime", nullable=true)
*/
private $date;`